# No route matches [GET] "/subjects/list"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck with this error when I try to access the list.html.erb page. Is there something wrong with the code?

**Error:** *No route matches [GET] "/subjects/list"*

**subjects_controller.rb**

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

    def list
        @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")

    end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

      get 'demo/index' 
end
```

**list.html.erb**

```
<div class="subject list">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subject.position %></td>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
        <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
        <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with the code?

The route is not declared properly as Ilya has pointed out. But there is a far better way of doing this using the Rails conventions.

The "list" action in rails is known as `index`. And the index action for subjects should be `[GET] "/subjects"`.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :subjects, only: [:index]
end
```

app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:

```
class SubjectsController
  # GET /subjects
  def index
    @subjects = Subject.order(position: :asc)
  end
end
```

You want to mode/rename your `list.html.erb` to `app/views/subjects/index.html.erb`.

Then when you want to add more routes to show, create, update etc. You can simply remove the `only` option:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :subjects
end
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html